# Sundaram's sieve in Common Lisp

Tags: functional-programming, common-lisp, primes

I have this [Sundaram's sieve](http://plus.maths.org/content/os/issue50/features/havil/index) to generate prime numbers up to `limit` in Common Lisp.

```
(defun sundaram-sieve (limit)
  (let ((numbers (range 3 (+ limit 1) 2))
        (half (/ limit 2))
        (start 4))
    (dolist (step (range 3 (+ limit 1) 2))
      (dolist (i (range start half step))
        (setf (nth (- i 1) numbers) 0))
      (setq start (+ start (* 2 (+ step 1))))
      (if (> start half)
          (return (cons 2 (remove-if #'zerop numbers)))))))
```

Here `range` is [defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13937652/596361) as:

```
(defun range (min max step)
   (loop for n from min below max by step
      collect n))
```

How can i make the code above more functional and idiomatic? The use of `setq` and `setf` bothers me, not to mention that it takes 10 seconds to calculate with `limit` equal 100000, when the equivalent code in Python runs almost instantly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  (let ((numbers (range 3 (+ limit 1) 2))
```

Above defines a list of numbers. Later you set various numbers to zero. That's not good for a list structure. Use a vector, an one-dimensional array.

```
(dolist (step (range 3 (+ limit 1) 2))
```

Creating the list and then iterating over it makes no sense. Use a LOOP statement directly.

```
  (dolist (i (range start half step))
```

Creating the list and then iterating over it makes no sense. Use a LOOP statement directly.

Example:

```
(defun sundaram-sieve (limit)
  (let ((numbers (coerce (cons 2 (range 3 (+ limit 1) 2)) 'vector))
        (half (/ limit 2))
        (start 4))
    (loop for step from 3 upto limit by 2 do
          (loop for i from start below half by step do
                (setf (aref numbers i) 0))
          (incf start (* 2 (1+ step)))
          (when (> start half)
            (return (remove 0 numbers))))))
```

Runs fast.

```
CL-USER 36 > (time (sundaram-sieve 100000))
Timing the evaluation of (SUNDARAM-SIEVE 100000)

User time    =        0.007
System time  =        0.000
Elapsed time =        0.004
Allocation   = 1646136 bytes
0 Page faults
#(2 3 5 7 11 13 17 ... 99971 99989 99991)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate up to `limit` but only up to `(isqrt limit)`.

Comment: The outer loop iterates upto limit by 2. That should be changed to upto (isqrt limit) by 2